# Best practice for catching exceptions in CompletableFutures

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I often find library methods which return CompletableFuture, and also have `throws Exception` in the function signature. As I understand it, exceptions thrown within these functions will not be caught by a try-catch since the future typically does not complete until long after the code has left the try-catch block. For this reason, we're told to attach an `.exceptionally()` to the CompletableFuture chain to handle these failures.

So I would like to be able to just write this:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> libFunction() throws Exception;

CompletableFuture<Void> caller() {

  return libFunction()
    .exceptionally(exception -> {
      // code to handle exception
    }) 
}
```

The problem is that java requires caller() to either have a try-catch block wrapped around the libFunction invocation, or have caller() include `throws Exception` in its signature. If I include a try-catch, it amounts to writing some useless exception handling code which can never get called, and is redundant to the code in the exceptionally block.

The other option is to add `throws Exception` to my function signature. But that means every function in the call chain, until .join() is called, needs to have `throws Exception` in it's signature. And afaict, the function could never actually throw an exception because if it did, CompletableFuture would [wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) the exception in a CompletionException, and pass it to .exceptionally.

So my question is how do I write good asynchronous code using CompletableFuture that doesn't require either unnecessary exceptions being added to all my function signatures or redundant try-catch blocks just to satisfy the compiler?

Update: A bit more context - I work with a framework which auto-generates signatures associated with gRPC service routes. These signatures themselves return CompletionStage. So technically the join is getting called by the framework, not by me. So it's not practical to just bubble up the Exception to where the join takes place since the top level function signature is autogenerated.

Comment: `CompletableFuture<Void> libFunction() throws Exception` tells me there could be _two_ different sources of exceptions. The actual method that creates the future could `throws Exception`, but then `CompletableFuture<Void>` may _separately_ complete exceptionally. There is no automatic wrapping of thrown exceptions into futures. The solution imo is remove all `throws Exception`, unless creating the future itself could cause such an exception. When you resolve the future (e.g. `#get`, `#then`, etc), you either handle the exception (`#exceptionally`) or allow it to propagate from that point.

Comment: By automatic wrapping, I'm referring to this from the docs: "In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a CompletionException holding the exception as its cause."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html

Comment: So there's two contexts: The code before you've made the future, and the code that is running inside of the future. The `throws Exception` bit on `#libFunction` would specify an exception _outside_ of the future that is returned. When it speaks to "dependent stages", it means further calls of `#then*` or `#whenComplete*` or `#exceptionally`, which take the old future and function and compose a new `CompletableFuture` wrapping them (a new `CompletionStage`).

Comment: @Rogue is correct. The method could throw *before* it creates the `CompletableFuture` to return to you. In that case, the exception is *now*, not in the future. If the method could never throw, aside from the *future* code throwing, there would be no need to declare it `throws Exception`, but if it *can*, and apparently it can, then you must catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: I would strongly suggest looking into the library code to see what it is actually doing, and how it can throw an exception. In other words, *use the source, Luke*.

Comment: I've looked at the code now, and that actually does make sense. Thanks for helping me understand that! These async functions were generated by OpenAPI, and it looks like the exception that's thrown is for problems building the arguments, and the exception that's returned asynchronously is for failures during transmission.

Answer (score 0):

This is all cleared up now thanks to @rogue's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78048481/best-practice-for-catching-exceptions-in-completablefutures#comment137594836_78048481). The way to think about this is that any function returning a completable future has both a synchronous and an asynchronous component. If the former throws an exception, it should be caught with a try-catch block. If the latter throws an exception, it's wrapped in a CompletionException, returned, and passed as the argument to the exceptionally block. So having both a try-catch and an exceptionally block is not redundant.

Thanks to both @rogue and @david-conrad for helping me understand this.